# How do you access an object with keys as a React child? - React Native

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, object, react-native

I am trying to display this JSON data:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":"1",
      "imagename":"dog"
   },
   {  
      "id":"2",
      "imagename":"cat"
   },
   {  
      "id":"3",
      "imagename":"mouse"
   },
   {  
      "id":"4",
      "imagename":"deer"
   },
   {  
      "id":"5",
      "imagename":"shark"
   },
   {  
      "id":"6",
      "imagename":"ant"
   }
]
```

Here is the current code that I have to display that data:

```
 componentDidMount(){
     fetch(`http://www.example.com/React/data.php`, {
     method: 'POST',
     headers: {
       'Accept': 'application/json',
       'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     },
   }).then((response) => response.json())
       .then((responseJson) => {

      this.data = responseJson;
      this.setState({ loading: false });


   }).catch((error) => {
     console.warn(error);
   });

}

     return(

         <View style = { styles.MainContainer }>
          <View>
           <Card>          
              <View>
              <Text>{this.data.id}</Text>
              <Text>{this.data.imagename}</Text>
             </View>
           </Card>
           </View>
         </View>
       );
```

My result is that nothing displays, but when I just have `this.data` I get the object with keys error again.

Looking up similar answers to find my problem, I then attempted to `.map`, but I kept getting `cannot not find variable: i`:

```
this.data =  responseJson.map(item => ({ ...item, i }))
```

And lastly here is the rest of my code for the attempt:

```
return(

     <View style = { styles.MainContainer }>
      <View>
       <Card>          
          <View key={i}>
          <Text>{item.id}</Text>
          <Text>{item.imagename}</Text>
         </View>
       </Card>
       </View>
     </View>
   );
```

When I put my json data into an array, nothing displays because (I'm guessing) there are no commas between the keys. Like this:

```
{"id":"1","imagename":"dog"}{"id":"2","imagename":"cat"}{"id":"3","imagename":"mouse"}{"id":"4","imagename":"deer"}{"id":"5","imagename":"shark"}{"id":"6","imagename":"ant"}
```

And if anyone needs to see my `data.php`:

**Echos Object**

```
    $dsql = "SELECT * FROM random";

$dresult = $con->query($dsql);

if ($dresult->num_rows >0) {


 while($drow[] = $dresult->fetch_assoc()) {

 $dtem = $drow;

 $djson = json_encode($dtem);


 }

} else {
}
echo $djson;
```

**Echos Array**

```
$dsql = "SELECT * FROM random";

$dresult = $con->query($dsql);

if ($dresult->num_rows >0) {


 while($drow = $dresult->fetch_assoc()) {

 $dtem = $drow;

 $djson = json_encode($dtem);
 echo $djson;

 }

} else {
}
```

Comment: You have to define the index (i variable) as the second parameter on map function, try to change to: ```this.data =  responseJson.map((item, i) => ({ //... More logic here }))```

Comment: @ricardoorellana hmm, I got this: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: i` I also tried doing this: `i: responseJson` and I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I can see an error on the way you pass the argument `i` on your map function, please take a look to this simple example of how to use map to render `<li>` elements.

```js
var dataSample = [
  { "id": "1", "imagename": "dog" },
  { "id": "2", "imagename": "cat" },
  { "id": "3", "imagename": "mouse" },
  { "id": "4", "imagename": "deer" },
  { "id": "5", "imagename": "shark" },
  { "id": "6", "imagename": "ant" }
];

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <ul>
    {dataSample.map((data, i) => {
        return <li key={i}>{i + ' - ' + data.imagename}</li>
    })}
    </ul>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I would I do this in React Native?

Comment: No, you should change the html elements by a valid `react-native` component like in your example . I just wanted to show you a working example of the map function on react.

Comment: Yes, I just had to ask the right question. And now I just need to figure out how to access the `id` in my `response.json`

Comment: I see, the responseJSON you have it's called an array of objects, because is made of array that contains objects. Do you still get the error when trying to reading it with the `map` function?

Comment: Oh ok, I never got to understand the terminology and no everything works now. I just need to access an object in an array using `this.state`